# How to get the list of queues from a server?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Any idea how to get a list of all queues from Artemis v2.6.x? 
I have tried to retrieve them from some MBeans under 
`org.apache.karaf.jmx`, but it do not work as I expected. 
Please share some working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few important notes:

- Artemis MBeans are under `org.apache.activemq.artemis` by default not `org.apache.karaf.jmx`  (although that is configurable using the `<jmx-domain>` element in broker.xml).
- By default the MBean names include the `name` of the broker (since multiple brokers can run in the same JVM). This name is configurable using the `<name>` element in broker.xml. The `name` is `localhost` by default. The broker `name` can be excluded from the MBean's name by setting `<jmx-use-broker-name>false</jmx-use-broker-name>` in broker.xml if desired.
- There are several methods to get queue names from the broker:

  - `getQueueNames()`: This method is on the `ActiveMQServerControl` MBean and returns a `String[]` of the names of all the queues defined on the broker.
  - `getQueueNames(String)`: This method is on the `ActiveMQServerControl` MBean and returns a `String[]` of the names of all the queues defined on the broker whose routing-type matches the input. Valid input values are `anycast` & `multicast`.
  - [API documentation for ActiveMQServerControl](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html).

You can find a working example of an MBean client accessing queue metrics in the `jmx` example shipped with Artemis. You can view the code for that example online [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/features/standard/jmx/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/example/JMXExample.java).

Here's a simple example of code to get the queue names from a broker running on localhost:

```
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.ActiveMQServerControl;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.ObjectNameBuilder;

public class JMXExample {

   public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
      ObjectName on = ObjectNameBuilder.DEFAULT.getActiveMQServerObjectName();
      JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi"), new HashMap());
      MBeanServerConnection mbsc = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
      ActiveMQServerControl serverControl = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(mbsc, on, ActiveMQServerControl.class, false);
      for (String queueName : serverControl.getQueueNames()) {
         System.out.println(queueName);
      }
      connector.close();
   }
}
```

See more details in the [Artemis Management documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/management.html).